# rails get address from google map using longtitude and latitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I am trying write an application that receives lat/lng and return appropriate location. (i.e I send the data lat/lng = 40.343545334/32.235308039 it returns for example New York) What should I use here? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Geocoder gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) for that. See [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder).